# How does single assignment in Erlang lead to more readable code?

Tags: erlang, referential-transparency

How does single assignment in Erlang lead to more readable code (referential transparency)?

Answer (score 2):

*Coding is easy,  debugging is hard.  Code to make debugging trivial.* -- Barry Rountree

With a single assignment, you can be sure that variable has one value in the whole function body. It makes debugging much easier. You can put debugging and logging whenever you want. You can easily spot the place where it gains its value and so on. Isn't it obvious?

Answer (score 1):

On of the goals of functional programs is to avoid [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29). In short this is a property of the code that it behaves exactly the same every time it's executed. That's why [shared state is being avoided](http://erlang.org/download/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf) and why developers often frown upon the [process dictionary](http://www.erlang.org/course/advanced) in Erlang. A pure functional language wouldn't have any side effects. Various functional languages try to formalize code that produces side effects, like for example [Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_IO_for_Imperative_Programmers).

Obviously, if the value assigned to a variable can be changed, then the same function executed twice would produce different result depending on the value contained in the variable. In OOP output from a function executed on an object produces a result that depends on the state contained in that object. So you can't understand the code properly without knowing the state contained in the object as well.

With single assignment the output doesn't depend on the state but only on the arguments passed to the function. This is especially useful when something crashed and you have a stack trace or you log a debug output from a function. You can read the code and assign values to each variable knowing that nothing would have altered those values if the same code was to be executed again.